# mssql_escape saves double apostrophe

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection, apostrophe

I am using the function below to escape my string before it is inserted into the DB. Though it actually inserts the double apostrophe into the database, and when I print it out it still has the double apostrophe. What is the right way to print the value out with the original single apostrophe?

```
function mssql_escape($var){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $var = stripslashes($var);
    }
    return str_replace("'", "''", $var);
}
```

Comment: You only need to double the apostrophes if you're building a SQL statement as a single string. I'm guessing you're not.

Comment: I am using the following:     $value = mssql_escape($_REQUEST['value']); 

$query = " INSERT INTO TableName(value) VALUES (?)"; $params = array($value); $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query, $params); if($stmt===false){die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a parameterised statement there is no need to double up the single quotes. This is the right way of doing things and is generally safe from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you! I'll implement this now.